# Как добавить больше одного варианта условия в списковом включении?

Tags: python, list

Списковые включения не поддерживают elif и else if. Возможно ли добавить больше одного условия в списковом включении, не используя другие конструкции?

Comment: Ну можно как пример [i if not i % 2 else i if not i % 3 else 0 for i in range(10)]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Я бы на код посмотрел, ну очень интересно.

Comment: @Kuchizu напиши как ответ, я подтвержу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Kuchizu напиши как ответ, я подтвержу.

```
[i if not i % 2 else i if not i % 3 else 0 for i in range(10)]
```